# Is pluginlib working on ROS2?

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-bouncy, pluginlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been fighting to port over some plugins to ROS2, and everything builds fine, but the plugins aren't discovered at runtime. Before I dig into this further, I'm wondering if this is expected to be working, and if so, is there any description of the changes between ROS 1 and ROS2?

Also are there any command line tools under ROS 2 for debugging? For example, in ROS1 there is `rospack plugins --attrib=plugin`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303005/is-pluginlib-working-on-ros2?/) by [Carl D](https://answers.ros.org/users/36816/carl-d/) on ROS Answers with karma: 303 on 2018-09-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz is using pluginlib in ROS 2 right now, so maybe you could use it as a reference.

> Also are there any command line tools under ROS 2 for debugging? For example, in ROS1 there is `rospack plugins --attrib=plugin`

Not right now. That would be a nice enhancement though :)

There's some small documentation here:

https://github.com/ros/pluginlib/blob/c0bbfaf8b22f3800bc3bd20414b9b15ea0aa52de/pluginlib/cmake/pluginlib_export_plugin_description_file.cmake#L23-L79

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Carl D](https://answers.ros.org/users/36816/carl-d/) on 2018-09-10**:
Not that I'll have time to do it for quite a while, but where is the right place to add the rospack functionality? Does it belong as part of the `ros2 pkg` command?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-09-10**:
Yeah, probably so. There might be room for a `ros2 pluginlib` type verb separately, but I'd have to think about that more. I always found the `--attrib=plugin` to be unnecessarily obtuse.

**Comment by [artivis](https://answers.ros.org/users/11816/artivis/) on 2019-06-20**:
Any update about the cli tool ??

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2021-06-23**:
Dear future person who Googled "ros 2 pluginlib": https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation/pull/1700